# RedDog.Search cannot make a search request

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cognitive-search

I have an app in which I need to use azure search with the help of RedDog.Search sdk (version 0.5.3-pre). Even though I'm able to use the IndexManagementClient to create indexes and upload documents, when trying to use IndexQueryClient to make a simple search I always get a pending request. This is my code:

```
ApiConnection connection = ApiConnection.Create("my-service", "my-key");

var client = new IndexQueryClient(connection);

try
{
  var results = await client.SearchAsync("companies", new SearchQuery()
    .OrderBy("name")
    .Count(true));

  foreach (var doc in results.Body.Records)
  {
    // Do something with the properties: result.Properties["title"], result.Properties["description"]
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Neither the foreach loop, nor the catch block are ever hit. The service name and key used for the connection are correct, because I've tried using them in the microsoft azure search sdk and it works fine.

This is how my index is mapped:

```
id Edm.String Key, Searchable, Sortable, Retrievable
name Edm.String Searchable, Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
adminEmails Collection(Edm.String) Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable
hrEmails Collection(Edm.String) Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable
description Edm.String Searchable, Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
shortDescription Edm.String Searchable, Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
image Edm.String Retrievable
thumbnail Edm.String Retrievable
country Edm.Int32 Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
city Edm.String Searchable, Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
postalCode Edm.String Searchable, Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
street Edm.String Retrievable
number Edm.String Retrievable
box Edm.String Retrievable
rating Edm.Int32 Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
boostFactor Edm.Int32 Filterable, Facetable, Sortable, Retrievable
tags Collection(Edm.String) Searchable, Filterable, Facetable, Retrievable
deleted Edm.Boolean Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
addedDate Edm.DateTimeOffset Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
changedDate Edm.DateTimeOffset Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
banExpirationDate Edm.DateTimeOffset Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
users Collection(Edm.String) Retrievable
currentJobs Collection(Edm.String) Retrievable
finishedJobs Collection(Edm.String) Retrievable
finishedJobsCount Edm.Int32 Filterable, Sortable, Retrievable
recommendations Collection(Edm.String) Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable
websites Collection(Edm.String) Searchable, Filterable, Retrievable

scoring profiles:
commonDields default profile fields: name (weight 1.5), shortDescription (weight 1.5), description (weight 1.5)     and websites (weight 1.5) no functions -> function aggregation sum
mostRecent type: Freshness, field: changedDate, interpolation: Linear, boost: 1.5
byRating type: Magnitude, field: rating, interpolation: Linear, boost: 1.5
byBoostFactor type: Magnitude, field: boostFactor, interpolation: Linear, boost: 3
byTags type: Tag, field: tags, interpolation: Linear, boost: 1.5
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a setting that I need to update in the Azure Search portal?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that RedDog.Search is a third party SDK not supported by Microsoft. Here is the official SDK from the Azure Search team: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Search

Comment: @Bruce Johnston - I know that this is a third party SDK, but I have already invested a considerable amount of time into making it work OO, with generic classes, for creating indexes and uploading documents, which I wouldn't like to lose. This is the only reason why I wouldn't want to switch to the microsoft SDK yet

Comment: Are there features we could add to the SDK that would make it easier to migrate?

Comment: Well, I don't know if these would help everybody, but I can tell you what I did to make my life easy:

Comment: - in order to index a class I made the following: I made it implement an interface in which I would set the index name, the scoring profiles and the suggesters. Then I have made custom property attributes in order to store the property name and the needed attributes (IsKey, IsSearchable, ...). I parsed everything in a generic repository, this way I wouldn't have to write several functions to create indexes for different classes (also, these functions would have to change as well if I decide to add other properties at some point in time).

Comment: This way I only have to call something like _repository<Company>.CreateIndex()

Comment: - in order to upload a document, I made 2 things: one was to add an ignore property attribute, so that I wouldn't have to upload properties that are not needed. The other thing was to parse the entity that I needed to upload, so that I would serialize non supported types (like custom objects) into JSON format and then make the actual upload.

Comment: These custom object properties are the main reason why I didn't choose the microsoft SDK, because , as I saw in your article, when you make a search, you retrive results mapped on your object: indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>(searchText, sp), therefore my custom objects will always be null.

Comment: The latest SDK now supports custom serialization via JSON.NET's IContractResolver and JsonConverter. That should enable most of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I didn't know you had this implemented. 
Looks like exactly what I need: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/AutoRest/src/Search/Search.Tests/Tests/Models Tx

Comment: It's a brand new feature that just shipped last week. Glad to help!